# How can class defined within another class know its parent?

Tags: c++, class, layout

```
class App
{
    public:
             App(int X, int Y, char* TITLE);
        void run(void);
    public: // Getters
        sf::RenderWindow *getWindow(void);
        sf::Event        *getEvent (void);
        sf::Keyboard     *getKboard(void);
    private: // Variables
        sf::RenderWindow window;
        sf::Event         event;
        sf::Keyboard     kboard;
        #include "game.hpp" // The definition of the Game class
        Game game;
};
```

The main loop.

```
void App::run(void)
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();
            game.run(); // works fine
        }
    }
}
```

The definition of the Game class:

```
class Game
{
    public:
             Game(void);
        void run(void);
};
```

**I want Game class to be able to access the variables of the App class. How?**

Method 1: Game class is able to call public functions of App.

Method 2: Game class is able to use protected variables of App.

```
class App
{
    public:
             App(int X, int Y, char* TITLE);
        void run(void);
    protected: // Variables
        sf::RenderWindow window;
        sf::Event         event;
        sf::Keyboard     kboard;
    private:
        #include "game.hpp" // The definition of the Game class
        Game game;
};
```

**Either way Game class needs to know its parent... How do I configure its constructor then?**

*I could also make the game class have its own variables, but that looses the point of using nested classes at all...*

---

**SOLUTION:** method 3, declare Game class as a friend of App.

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
class App
{
    friend class Game; // THE SOLUTION
    public:
             App(const int X, const int Y, const char* NAME); // now using const
        void run(); // not using void to identify empty arguments list anymore
    private: // Variables
        sf::RenderWindow window;
        sf::Event         event;
        sf::Keyboard     kboard;
};
#include "game.hpp"
```

And now the game.hpp:

```
class Game
{
    public:
            // A little bit of redundacy here, but it works!!!
            Game(const int X, const int Y, const char* TITLE) :app(X, Y, TITLE)
            { /* and the initialization of the Game class itself... */}
       void run()
            { app.run(); /* And the running process of Game class itself*/};
     private:
       App app; // Now the Game class owns App and not contrary
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing a relationship between classes does not help you since you need one object (i.e. instance) to be able to refer to a different object. If you want one object to be able to have access to members of a different object, then you need there to be a reference to that other object.

For instance, you could pass a reference to the instance of `App` when you call `run`.

```
class Game
{
    public:
             Game();
        void run(const App& app);
};
```

Or if you prefer, you could make a private member of type `App&` and initialize that reference in the constructor.

Personally, I see no reason for your nesting, nor your distinct header files. These classes are bound together, so I'd put them in the same header. It might look like this:

```
class App; // forward declaration

class Game
{
    public:
        void run(const App& app);
};

class App
{
    public:
             App(const int X, const int Y, const char* TITLE);
        void run();
    private:
        Game game;
};
```

As an aside, it is not idiomatic C++ to use `void` to indicate an empty parameter list. And you should use `const` where possible to make it feasible for any consumers of the class to pass const objects.

Comment: @MariusMacijauskas So make a forward declaration. Why are you using `#include` for this anyway?

Comment: I don't know, I'm new to programming. I'm only learning. The include statement seemed to be the only way to defend the project from incomplete type errors AND make the game class a separate header.

Comment: I don't think you want that class to be in a separate header, since they are so closely related. You cannot take one without the other. I also see no particular reason for the classes to be nested like that. You can make a forward declaration.

Comment: Done! Not the most elegant solution, but it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide it with a pointer or reference to its parent

```
class Game
{
public:
    explicit Game(App & app) : app(app) {}
    void run(void);
private:
    App & app;
};
```

Since C++11 (and in earlier versions of some popular compilers), being a nested class, this has access to all members of `App`. On some pre-2011 compilers, you'll need a `friend class Game;` declaration in `App` if it needs to access private or protected members.

Comment: Thanks! Used your friend class sugestion. It's sad I can't mark multiple answers as correct...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the reference to the `App` class into the game class like this:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game(App &app);
    void run(void);

private:
    App & m_app;
};
```

Then in the definition of the constructor, you can do this:

```
Game::Game(App &app) :
    m_app(app)
{
   // Game constructor stuff here.
}
```

Then, in the App constructor, you can do this:

```
App::App(int X, int Y, char* TITLE) :
    game(*this)
{
    // App constructor stuff here.
}
```

How you want to provide access to the members of `App` is your choice, you can either make it a friend class, or provide public accessor methods.

Comment: Done it as you suggested, now App has a friend class Game!